# Send email based on each specific field that is updated

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017 Trigger on Table
I have the following trigger running, and it works. However, I want to send a different email section based on specific fields that get updated. I basically want to use the SQL Server Send Mail code to send to a different user for a different field. I was wondering if there was some way to combine the statement? I hope I'm asking this correctly! My SQL is as the AT&T commercial...JUST OK! So if you can help please provide the code if this in fact can be done.  For example:

Send/do this if firstname updated:

```sql
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sample1.com',
      @subject = 'Send email for sample1',
      @body = 'Please start a background check'
```

Send/do this if last name updated

```sql
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sample2.com',
      @subject = 'Send email for sample2',
      @body = 'Please start a background check'
```

Send/do this is nationality updated.

```sql
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sample3.com',
      @subject = 'Send email for sample3',
      @body = 'Please start a background check'
```

```sql
ALTER trigger [dbo].[updatePerson] on
[dbo].[person]
for update
as
 
      declare @personId int;
      declare @firstname varchar(50);
      declare @lastname varchar(50);
      declare @nationality varchar(100);
      declare @activity varchar(100);
 
      select @personId = s.personId from inserted s;
      select @firstname = s.firstname from inserted s;
      select @lastname = s.lastname from inserted s;
      select @nationality = s.nationality from inserted s;
 
      if update(firstname)
                  set @activity = 'Updated person firstname'
      if update(lastname)
                  set @activity = 'Updated person lastname'
      if update(nationality)
                  set @activity = 'Updated person nationality'
 
      
 
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sampletriggernamen@gmail.com',
      @subject = ' follow the sampleaction you need to take. http://test.aspx',
      @body = 'Please start a background check'
```

Comment: Sending an email from a `TRIGGER` is generally a bad idea. If the email sends to fail, for example, then so too will the transaction and thus the row won't be updated. The above `TRIGGER`, however, is more fatally flawed; it assumes a DML operation only ever effects 1 row. A DML statement affects one or more rows and the above will not work as you expect if there are more rows. Ideally fix the flaw and then put the data into a pooling table; then send the emails from there. Even better, send the email from the application layer; that's really where this logic should be.

Comment: In addition, connecting to SMTP servers can involve all kinds of delays and timeouts which slow things down to a crawl.

Comment: You also start with *"SQL Server 2017 Trigger on Table"* but your tags say [tag:sql-server-2016]. Which are you *actually* using?

Comment: @Larnu, sql SERVER 2017. Sorry for that type.

Comment: There are no delays connecting to SQL server. It actually works very without any delay but I have a requirement to send notifications to different users because different users own the updates for different fields. I've actually looked at some other systems via searches and they are doing a very similar thing.

Comment: No one has mentioned delays connecting to SQL Server, we're talking about delays/issues connecting to your SMTP (Email) server - which can happen in any system. The way you should do this is put a record in a queue table and then have another, non-time-sensitive, service pulling records off the queue and sending emailing them. That aside as Larnu has said you are assuming `Inserted` has only a single record... you have to correct that before anything else will work.

Comment: And what should happen if 2 or 3 columns are updated at the same time? Which template to use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows how to handle multiple rows by looping through the `Inserted` pseudo-table. And how to detect changes in values.

As far as sending a different email per change type, you already had an `IF` statement to assign your `@activity` so just expand that to set the values to be emailed.

But as has been commented above, sending emails in a trigger is a very bad idea. Instead you should insert the data to be emailed into a queue table and then have another service processing the queue.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[updatePerson] on
[dbo].[person]
for update
as
begin
    set nocount on;
     
    declare @personId int, @firstname varchar(50), @lastname varchar(50), @nationality varchar(100), @activity varchar(100)
      , @firstNameModified bit, @lastNameModified bit, @nationalityModified bit
      , @profile_name sysname, @recipients varchar(max), @subject nvarchar(255), @body nvarchar(max);

    select
        I.personId
        , convert(bit, case when coalesce(I.firstname,'') <> coalesce(D.firstname,'') then 1 else 0 end) firstnameModified
        , I.firstname
        , convert(bit, case when coalesce(I.lastname,'') <> coalesce(D.lastname,'') then 1 else 0 end) lastnameModified
        , I.lastname
        , convert(bit, case when coalesce(I.nationality,'') <> coalesce(D.nationality,'') then 1 else 0 end) nationalityModified
        , I.nationality
    into #updatePerson_temp
    from Inserted I
    -- Because its an 'update' trigger we can inner join
    inner join Deleted D on D.personId = I.personId
    where coalesce(I.firstname,'') <> coalesce(D.firstname,'')
    or coalesce(I.lastname,'') <> coalesce(D.lastname,'')
    or coalesce(I.nationality,'') <> coalesce(D.nationality,'');

    while exists (select 1 from #updatePerson_temp) begin
        -- Get first record to handle
        select top 1 @personId = personId
            , @firstnameModified = firstnameModified
            , @firstname = firstname
            , @lastnameModified = firstnameModified
            , @lastname = lastname
            , @nationalityModified = nationalityModified
            , @nationality = nationality
        from #updatePerson_temp;

        -- Following assumes only one change per record, modify to suit
        if @firstnameModified = 1 begin
            select @activity = 'Updated person firstname'
                , @profile_name = 'Echo System'
                , @recipients = 'sample1.com'
                , @subject = 'Send Email for Sample1'
                , @body = 'Please start a background check';
        end; else if @lastnameModified = 1 begin
            select @activity = 'Updated person lastname'
                , @profile_name = 'Echo System'
                , @recipients = 'sample2.com'
                , @subject = 'Send Email for Sample2'
                , @body = 'Please start a background check';
        end; else if @nationalityModified = 1 begin
            select @activity = 'Updated person nationality'
                , @profile_name = 'Echo System'
                , @recipients = 'sample3.com'
                , @subject = 'Send Email for Sample2'
                , @body = 'Please start a background check';
        end;

        -- Instead of sending the email here, queue it for later
        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = @profile_name
            , @recipients = @recipients
            , @subject = @subject
            , @body = @body;

        -- Delete handled record
        delete from #updatePerson_temp where personId = @personId;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Dale K. Your code worked very well! I will look at the values in a table and having a service do it also. Right now I'm searching and exploring ideas.