# Concatenate a parameter value with a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am using SQL Server 2017. I have code that is working well for what I am applying it to. However, I would like to send the parameter value with some text/string. I have tried many formats to combine or concatenate the two. I have tried this
@body = @AssociateTaskID + 'you have been assigned this id';
also tried this @body = @AssociateTaskID + + 'you have been assigned this id';
I get syntax errors on both. Is there any way to do this and make it work? If so, what's the syntax?

```
   Begin
      declare @AssociateTaskID int;
      declare @TaskAction_A1_assigned varchar(50);
      declare @TaskAction_A1_started varchar(100);
      declare @TaskAsction_A1_completed varchar(100);

      select @AssociateTaskID = s.AssociateTaskID from inserted s;
      select @TaskAction_A1_assigned = s.TaskAction_A1_assigned from inserted s;
  select @TaskAction_A1_started = s.TaskAction_A1_started from inserted s;
      select @TaskAsction_A1_completed = s.TaskAsction_A1_completed from inserted s;


   ------Send notification to TaskAction_A1_owner
     
    if update(TaskAction_A1_assigned)

      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sampleemailer2@gmail.com',
      @subject = 'Echo System Notification',
      @body = @AssociateTaskID;
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: You don't tell us what those syntax error are. `SET @Variable = @Variable + ' Some String';` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Also, this looks like it's part of a trigger. If so, it's fatally flawed; it assumes a DML statement effects **one** row; that is not true. Also, sending an email from a trigger is a bad idea; put the data in a pooling table and then use a scheduled task to email the data from there.

Comment: It is part of a trigger - which was the previous question where it was duly noted that this approach is very flawed.

Comment: But then, I told you this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053807/send-email-based-on-each-specific-field-that-is-updated#comment113268610_64053807), so it appears you've ignored my warning...

Comment: Depending on circumstance (always) you could check to see if more than 1 row was inserted and then throw an exception if multi row.  Then write the cursor as if 1 row is the only possibility.  Not recommended for large instances but if it's tightly controlled I've seen this done without negative issues arising

Comment: *"I've seen this done without negative issues arising"* Significant performance degradation isn't a negative issue?

Comment: The multi-row check?  That's a nothing.  Or the sending of the message within the trigger?  Of course I agree with you that's it's a much better approach to remove sending the message from the trigger.

Comment: I meant putting a `CURSOR` in the trigger, @SteveC .

Comment: O my, no of course not.  You should know I'm agreeing with you.  The solution in the link above is not ideal.

Comment: The key issue for the OP is the string_variable should be a constant.  Assigning the concatenation to a variable should allow them to execute the proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concatenation could be assigned to a variable.  Something like this

```
      declare 
        @AssociateTaskID            int,
        @TaskAction_A1_assigned     varchar(50),
        @TaskAction_A1_started      varchar(100),
        @TaskAsction_A1_completed   varchar(100),
        @Message                    nvarchar(4000);

      select @AssociateTaskID = s.AssociateTaskID,
             @TaskAction_A1_assigned = s.TaskAction_A1_assigned,
             @TaskAction_A1_started = s.TaskAction_A1_started,
             @TaskAsction_A1_completed = s.TaskAsction_A1_completed
      from inserted s;

      select @Message=concat(cast(@AssociateTaskID as nvarchar(12)), N'you have been assigned this id');
     
    --if update(TaskAction_A1_assigned)

      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Echo System',
      @recipients = 'sampleemailer2@gmail.com',
      @subject = 'Echo System Notification',
      @body = @Message;
```

Comment: No performance issues at all. This user group will never grow to more than 75 users and there is only one application running. We have tested this with over 70 records and each and every time the correct record is updated. It actually works exactly like we want it to perform. And that is without any issues.

Comment: The following from Steve C worked well. Just ran the code and it sent the message perfectly with the id and string information. Thanks for the input. 

 select @Message=concat(cast(@AssociateTaskID as nvarchar(12)), N'you have been assigned this id');
     
    --if update(TaskAction_A1_assigned)

Comment: Ha, there is no ideal system (mine included).  If it meets the requirements and you understand each piece then it's a great system.  :)  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to turn this `int` to a string. `concat()` comes handy for its implicit string conversion feature:

```
@body = concat('You have been assigned this task: ', @AssociateTaskID);
```